# Usar un JFXButton creado en javaFx y poder cambiar sus propiedades en distintas clases

Tags: java, javafx

He creado un archivo `.fxml` que contiene un `JFXButton`, he creado su respectivo controlador implementando la clase `Initializable`, de la siguiente forma:

```
package recursoselectronicos.management.controllers;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class AlertController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }
 
}
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo es posible usar el JFXButton y poder cambiar sus propiedades en distintas clases, por ejemplo, establecer un texto: `btn.setText("texto");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia a

```
public JFXButton btn;
```